# Does the program stop if I keep holding down the keyboard?

Tags: operating-system

Pressing the keyboard triggers an interrupt.

Then, EXECUTE of CPU is finished and interrupt check is performed, and ISR is executed.
But if I don't take the keyboard off, the interrupt will continue to occur, and I think that the program won't die.
But even if I keep pressing the keyboard while playing the game, the program doesn't die.

I think the operating system is blocking the keyboard interrupt, but I'm curious to know what it is.

Comment: The os isn't blocking anything. The keyboard cannot trigger an interrupt. It is the os which asks the xHCI to read the keyboard's state every 8ms and the xHCI triggers an interrupt when it has placed that state in RAM where the os asked. The keyboard is already polled at the maximum speed at which it can answer.

Comment: For details see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72326062/understanding-how-operating-systems-store-retrieve-io-device-input/72327222#72327222 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70582348/how-to-interpret-0000290000000000-sent-by-my-keyboard-as-usb-payload/70657582#70657582